# Select multiple columns and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame

df_dataset=

```
CustomerId   Surname    Gender    Birth Date     City        Salary          Country
15634602     Hargrave   Female    1979-12-18     Marseile    101348.88       France
15647311     Hill       Female    1980-08-15     Barcelona   112542.58       Spain
15619304     Onio       Female    1979-11-01     Marseile    113931.57       France
15701354     Boni       Female    1982-08-24     Paris       93826.63        France
15737888     Mitchell   Female    1978-01-09     Madrid      79084.10        Spain
```

I want to know the customerid, surname of the highest salary in country Spain

```
df_dataset[['CustomerId','Surname','Salary']].groupby['Country'=='Spain'].sort_values['Salary',ascending=False]
```

it gives me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `groupby['Country' == 'Spain']` since `groupby` is a method instead of an indexed object and it expected column names as part of its arguments instead of condition like `'Country'=='Spain'`. If you need filtering `df_dataset` by `Country`, you should use `df_dataset[df_dataset['Country'] == '<country name>']` instead before proceeding with getting the maximum salary. Does this code give you the expected output?

```
df_dataset[df_dataset['Country'] == 'Spain'].groupby(['Country'], sort=True)['Salary'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using loc and group by and then use pandas query to filter.

```
df_dataset[['CustomerId','Surname','Country','Salary']].loc[df_dataset.groupby(["CustomerId", "Surname"])["Salary"].idxmax()].query('Country=="Spain"')
```